# sp2 hybridization Group V elements

Tags: hybridization

I'm confused about $\mathrm{sp^2}$ hybridization in the formation of $\ce{NO3-}$ ion. Valence electrons of N are $\mathrm{(2s)^2}$ and $\mathrm{(2p)^3}$.

Is one of $\mathrm{2s}$ electrons kicked up to one of the $\mathrm{2p}$ orbitals, and then the remaining $\mathrm{2s}$ electron hybridized with the two remaining $\mathrm{2p}$ orbitals which have unpaired electrons? If so, that gives $\mathrm{sp^2}$ orbitals to bond with $\mathrm{p}$ orbitals of the oxygen atoms.  However, there is now that remaining unhybridized $\mathrm{p}$ orbital of nitrogen, which has 2 electrons, so how can it be involved in $\pi$ bonding?

I would appreciate someone explaining this. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but my book doesn't have an explanation of $\mathrm{sp^2}$ hybridization for Group V elements.

Comment: So the lone pair of nitrogen provides both electrons for the delocalized pi bond, and the oxygen atoms do not contribute an electron to the delocalized pi bond?

Comment: I withdrew my earlier comment. Although I could *simply* share with you that number of electron regions around an atom is an indication to *quickly* figure out its hybridization, I am not able to explain this in detail, because I have a sub question when looking at yours: I am not sure how the sp3 hybridized oxygen that has formal charge -1 is making a bond with sp2 nitrogen which has +1 formal charge.

Comment: @bonCodigo, oxygen is thought as being unhybridized in this case. Rather, you think of the whole ion as being composed of $\mathrm{sp2}$-hybridized $\ce{N+}$, two unhybridized $\ce{O-}$, and one unhybridized $\ce{O}$.

Comment: @Wildcat [this has been *eating* me.](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/34416/7450) Almost for all ions $\ce{CO3^{-2}}$ etc

Comment: @bonCodigo, well in principle, you can invoke $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridization for $\ce{O-}$ ions as well as $\mathrm{sp^2}$ hybridization for $\ce{O}$ atom. But, it won't change anything, so you don't need it.

Answer (score 4):

> However, there is now that remaining unhybridized p orbital of
>   nitrogen, which has 2 electrons, so how can it be involved in π
>   bonding?

Everything is more-or-less "right" up to these point. The thing you're missing is that there is only one electron in the unhybridized $\mathrm{p}$ orbital of $\ce{N}$ atom since to get the following usual configuration of $\ce{NO3-}$ ion (image courtesy of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrate))

[image]

with *two* negatively charged $\ce{O-}$ ions one electron has to be moved from $\ce{N}$ atom to $\ce{O}$ atom first. Now note that since all $\ce{O}$ atom are equivalent to each other we need to invoke the concept of the *resonance*, but for simplicity think first about any single of the resonance structure above.

So, formally we start by having:

- one $\ce{N}$ atom with $\mathrm{(1s)^2 (2s)^2 (2p)^3}$ electron configuration;
- two $\ce{O}$ atoms with $\mathrm{(1s)^2 (2s)^2 (2p)^4}$ electron configuration;
- and one $\ce{O-}$ ion with $\mathrm{(1s)^2 (2s)^2 (2p)^5}$ electron configuration;

In the first step we transfer one of the $p$-electrons from $\ce{N}$ atom to an $\ce{O}$ atom, so we end up with:

- one $\ce{N+}$ ion with $\mathrm{(1s)^2 (2s)^2 (2p)^2}$ electron configuration;
- one $\ce{O}$ atom with $\mathrm{(1s)^2 (2s)^2 (2p)^4}$ electron configuration;
- and two $\ce{O-}$ ions with $\mathrm{(1s)^2 (2s)^2 (2p)^5}$ electron configuration;

At the next step we invoke the $\mathrm{sp^2}$ hybridization of $\ce{N+}$ ion, so that we get:

- one $\mathrm{sp^2}$-hybridized $\ce{N+}$ ion with $\mathrm{(1s)^2 (sp^2)^3 (2p)^1}$ electron configuration;
- one $\ce{O}$ atom with $\mathrm{(1s)^2 (2s)^2 (2p)^4}$ electron configuration;
- and two $\ce{O-}$ ions with $\mathrm{(1s)^2 (2s)^2 (2p)^5}$ electron configuration;

Finally, we form bonds as follows:

- One $\sigma$ bond between the $\mathrm{sp^2}$-hybridized $\ce{N+}$ ion and an $\ce{O-}$ ion in forming which we use 1 of the total 3 $\mathrm{sp^2}$-electrons of $\ce{N+}$ ion and the only unpaired $\mathrm{2p}$-electron of $\ce{O-}$ ion;
- Another identical $\sigma$ bond between the $\mathrm{sp^2}$-hybridized $\ce{N+}$ and another $\ce{O-}$ ion; here we use 1 of the remaining 2 $\mathrm{sp^2}$-electrons of $\ce{N+}$ ion and the only unpaired $\mathrm{2p}$-electron of $\ce{O-}$ ion;
- Yet another $\sigma$ bond, but this time between the $\mathrm{sp^2}$-hybridized $\ce{N+}$ ion and the $\ce{O}$ atom in forming which we use the last remaining $\mathrm{sp^2}$-electron of $\ce{N+}$ ion and 1 out of total 2 unpaired $\mathrm{2p}$-electrons of $\ce{O-}$ ion;
- What remains now is one unhybridized $\mathrm{2p}$-electrons of $\ce{N+}$ ion and one unpaired $\mathrm{2p}$-electrons of $\ce{O-}$ ion which are used to form the $\pi$ bond.

Pictorially (image courtesy of Professor [Peter Bird](http://faculty.concordia.ca/bird/c241/notes_ch3-shriver.html)):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, thank, thank you!  I was so frustrated trying to figure this out, and couldn't find an explanation on the web or in other textbooks.  I wish your clear, logical explanation was in texts; they seem to have only the simplest hybridization examples.  I know this took some time to write your response; I,

Comment: (to continue) I'm very appreciative of your kindness.  Am sure others looking for an explanation of NO3- on the web will benefit as well.