How do we measure the hybridisation of a molecule experimentally?
I've seen here that you can measure the amount of s-character in the hybrid orbitals of a molecule experimentally. Isn't hybridisation supposed to be a purely theoretical concept, and as such isn't the hybridisation of a molecule imaginary, with no real existence? If we are able to experimentally determine the amount of s-character in a molecule doesn't that mean that hybridisation is a real phenomenon? If not, what are we actually measuring, and how does it correlate to s-character?(Note: I know nothing about NMR spectroscopy)

Standard scientific approach: The system is much too complex to solve exactly. So we make a model. From the model we can make predictions. We can fit those predictions to experiment and say what that means within the model. It doesn't mean the model is is the true description of what is actually happening.

See coulson's theorem and this question

Hybridisation is a theory. And like all theories, it can be accepted or not. But, if hybridization is not accepted, it is much more difficult to explain that the four bonds in CH4 make a tetrahedron, for example. So the hybridisation cannot be measured. It helps understanding. That's all.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34323/why-does-hybridization-significantly-matter-for-organic-chemistry

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/32051/9961

We don't measure hybridisation. We measure the structure of molecules. Tweaking the very simple idea of hybridisation to explain more complicated structures is what is often done to avoid the impossible quantum mechanical calculations that might constitute a "real" explanation of the observed structure.

"Isn't hybridisation supposed to be a purely theoretical concept ..." You have entered the realm of philosophy of science. Science is largely a collection of theoretical concepts with explanatory and predictive power.

I wouldn't go as far and can hybridisation a theory, it's a model (molecular orbital theory, as an interpretation) and maybe part of a theory (valence bond, as a starting point). Doesn't diminish the usefulness as a teaching device if you understand the limitations.


[OP] I've seen here that you can measure the amount of s-character in the hybrid orbitals of a molecule experimentally

It is the opposite. You can measure the J-coupling constant between a carbon and a hydrogen. This is influenced by the electron density at the two nuclei and in between, also a real thing but a little harder to measure. Then, you can correlate your findings with any theory about bonding you might be looking at.

[OP] Isn't hybridisation supposed to be a purely theoretical concept, and as such isn't the hybridisation of a molecule imaginary, with no real existence?

Hybridization is a convenient description of bonding. It is incomplete but is useful in a limited but important domain of chemistry (organic chemistry). In that sense it connects to reality.

[OP] If we are able to experimentally determine the amount of s-character in a molecule doesn't that mean that hybridisation is a real phenomenon? If not, what are we actually measuring, and how does it correlate to s-character?

The electron density is real. Orbitals in multi-electron systems are not real (no experiment to measure them), and so hybridization is not real in this sense either.

Unlike an orbital model of a molecule, the electron density is a physical observable. There are therefore advantages in interpreting the electron density to obtain information about bonding that are not as widely appreciated as they deserve to be.
Source: https://doi.org/10.1021/ed079p1141


"Orbitals in multi-electron systems are not real (no experiment to measure them)" - Orbitals, i.e. one electron wavefunctions, in a many electron system are not real full stop. They are a theory about bonding which may people look at, but ultimately are an approximation to the true many body wavefunction.

Could you specify more about the relation between the j coupling constant and s character and how this relation makes sense. Also what exactly does the j coupling constant represent?

@Mayo You said yourself you know nothing about NMR spectroscopy, so I'll keep it simple. The J coupling constant represents how strongly two nuclei are "talking to each other". The mechanical analogy are coupled oscillators where the two oscillations are slightly or strongly coupled.

How does that relate even remotely to s character though?

Electrons in different orbitals have different radial distribution. For example, the p orbital has a node at the nucleus and the s orbital does not.

So we calculate that distribution via the j coupling constant and then relate it to s character?
