# Hybridization of oxygen in Nitrate ion and the location/bond of nitrogen's lone pair

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hybridization, valence-bond-theory

I have tried to apply the rules and basics that I learnt so far. But I am confused about the hybridization of oxygen atoms which are making the single bond in nitrate ion.

Following are the steps I used. The average bond order of 4/3 makes the molecule unstable. 
[image]

Based on the steps, the single bonds are made of $\ce{sp^3}$ of oxygen and $\ce{sp^2}$ of nitrogen, the bonds are sigma bonds. However that doesn't seem like the case. If I look at $\ce{HNO3}$ dissociation equation in the water, lone electron pair of nitrogen is entirely shared with (co-ordinative covalent bond) one of the oxygens making a single bond.

$\ce{ HNO3(aq) -> H+(aq) + NO3^{-}(aq) }$

But considering $\ce{NO3}$ ion individually, without thinking about nitric acid, I can't find the long pair to be in the same type of co-ordinative bond. Isn't there an unbonding sp2 electron with nitrogen (probably one from the lone pair)?

The other issue, why isn't oxygen hybridizing to be $\ce{sp^3}$ here? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You indeed can think that these two $\ce{O-}$ are sp3-hybdiridzed. But I would rather explicitly call them $\ce{O-}$ rather then just $\ce{O}$.

Comment: nintrate-ion is isoelectronic to carbonate ion. The bonding is *very* similar except that in nitrate due to positive charge on nitrogen, the bonds are stronger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual structure of the nitrate ion is symmetrical. It forms a trigonal planar molecule.

This means that the bonds between oxygen and nitrogen are *all the same*. The resonance structures are a simple way to explain that structure using two-electron bonds. In reality the "extra" electron is delocalised across all three bonds (this will involve the nitrogen lone pair and nitrogen will be sp2 with no *free* lone pair).

The average bond order will be, as you calculate 4/3 but this doesn't, as you claim, make the molecule unstable.